# Deleted row in tableview is reappearing when navigating back

Tags: ios, uitableview

Have friendsviewcontroller in which have uibarbuttonItem to edit friends list and other uibarbuttonitem to create groups for group chatrooms.

Have multiple segue for switching view controllers.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title = @"Groups";
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self
                                                                         action:@selector(actionNew)];
self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
chatrooms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
if ([PFUser currentUser] != nil)
{
    [self refreshTable];
}
else LoginUser(self);
}

#pragma mark - User actions
- (void)actionNew
 {
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Create New Group" message:nil delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
 }

#pragma mark - UIAlertViewDelegate
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:    (NSInteger)buttonIndex=
 {
if (buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
{
    UITextField *textField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@""] == NO)
    {
        PFObject *object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:PF_CHATROOMS_CLASS_NAME];
        object[PF_CHATROOMS_NAME] = textField.text;
        [object saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
        {
            if (error == nil)
            {
                [self refreshTable];
            }
            else [ProgressHUD showError:@"Network error."];
        }];
    }
}
 }
- (void)refreshTable
 {
[ProgressHUD show:nil];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PF_CHATROOMS_CLASS_NAME];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
{
    if (error == nil)
    {
        [chatrooms removeAllObjects];
        for (PFObject *object in objects)
        {
            [chatrooms addObject:object];
        }
        [ProgressHUD dismiss];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    else [ProgressHUD showError:@"Network error."];
}];
 }

#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [chatrooms count];
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (cell == nil) cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

PFObject *chatroom = chatrooms[indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = chatroom[PF_CHATROOMS_NAME];

return cell;
 }

 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    PFObject *chatroom = [chatrooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [chatrooms removeObjectAtIndex:chatroom];
    //[chatrooms removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];    
}
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
PFObject *chatroom = chatrooms[indexPath.row];
NSString *roomId = chatroom.objectId;
CreateMessageItem([PFUser currentUser], roomId, chatroom[PF_CHATROOMS_NAME]);
ChatView *chatView = [[ChatView alloc] initWith:roomId];
chatView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:chatView animated:YES];
 }
```

Deleted row in table view reappears when navigate back to the TableView

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    PFObject *chatroom = [chatrooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [chatrooms removeObjectAtIndex:chatroom];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];   
}
}
```

Im unable to locate what piece of code i m missing or what exactly i m doing wrong.

If anyone can please point out to that.

Will appreciate so much.

Thanks.

Comment: We need to see how and where chatrooms is created, and how you navigate back to TableView.

Comment: chatroom is an Integer or an object?

Comment: chatroom is an NSMutableArray object declared as an ivar

Comment: is chatrooms multidimensional? seems like you need to do this [chatrooms removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  which i assume is what @user1120133 was hinting at

Comment: have already tried this [chatrooms removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; but same results. Tableview row reappears

Comment: well do you persist chatrooms anywhere and not removing it from there?  perhaps your view is reloading from where you persist the data?  and it is simply reloading when your view reappears

Comment: You need to edit your question to show how you create chatrooms. Also, we need to know how you go back to TableView. Are you really going back, or are you creating a new instance?

Comment: Does the view controller populate the data source of the table view when navigating back? Show us the code of `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` and unwind method if the view controller has one.

Comment: i just updated my post pls check it

Comment: viewdidappear calls this .. [self refreshTable];  you dont appear to be deleting the chatroom from wherever the data is coming from so its just going to refresh the table from that place every time the view appears

Comment: so i think instead of refreshing table rather i should be using this - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When committing deletion, your code removes objects from `chatrooms` which is data source of the table view in your case, but this happens in your app's memory, the **source** from which `chatrooms` is populated does not change. Thus, speaking in MVC, the app's model state is not updated after the view's state is changed.

Every time the table view is showed up, your code populates `chatrooms` in `refreshTable`, if the model's state hasn't been changed, the code gets same list as before, thus the table view doesn't change.

**EDIT:** Instead of using another approach to refresh the table view, you need to think about what does your app do in this table view. If user can delete stuff in the table view, should your app update model (This model can be a local or remote database, a property list file, etc.) too? If yes, then update model when user inserts or deletes rows in the table view; well, if not, then you are asking a question that is not a problem, or maybe the table view should turn off editing.

**EDIT1:**

If you do need to update data, based on your code, you may need to do something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
        commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle 
        forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        PFObject *chatroom = [chatrooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [chatrooms removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:PF_CHATROOMS_CLASS_NAME];
        [query deleteChatroom:chatroom];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] 
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];    
    }
}
```

That is, you may need to implement method `deleteChatroom:` of class `PFQuery`.

Comment: i just had a Déjà vu moment :)

Comment: Yes you are very right because of refresh table it is not deleting rows and refreshing the same old rows again and again. In this table view basically you add or remove friends from the list and create group chat rooms but another feature i wanted to add is that what if you want to delete the group chat room

Comment: That's a new question. Your app loads data from source which stores data about friends and chatrooms. This **source** should provide interface to delete stuff. And your app should delete stuff through this interface. @user1120133

Comment: i added reloadData instead of refreshing table but now it is not deleting rows anymore crashing app with message Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 140378874219152 beyond bounds [0 .. 12]'

Comment: you need to sort out things first, my friend. You may have to rewrite part of your app, not just a few lines of code. Things like this happens when you just changed one or two lines of code to try to make something work. Don't rush to code without clear thinking. @user1120133

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Really appreciate. You right i need to implement method deletechatroom of PFQuery Class.

Comment: i tried this way now and it worked - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        PFObject * chatroom = [chatrooms objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [chatroom delete];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }} only problem now is that when i hit delete button it doesn't goes away but when i navigate back that group chatroom is gone

Comment: In console i get warning message that A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. 
 Break on warnParseOperationOnMainThread() to debug.

Comment: You didn't remove object from `chatrooms`. As to the warning, it seems you are doing CPU-intense operations on main thread. That's not related to this question. Ask a new question if needed. @user1120133